# How to get the server name or IP address in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

In my svelte app I'd like to be able to find out the server name or IP address where the app is hosted, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean getting the the host, you can simply use `location.hostname`. This also works on vanilla js obviously.

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hostname.asp